# trying to call a Java-Object in Octave

Tags: java, octave, classnotfoundexception

Hey Guys im trying to call a Java-Object in Octave.
The Javaclasspath and everything else is set.

When i try to call a own created function like this:

```
>> x = javaObject('server_console.Server_Client')
```

I get this Error:

```
error: [java] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: server_console.Server_Client
```

But if i use Basic function it works fine.

```
<Java object: java.lang.Float>

>> javaMethod('floatToIntBits', 'java.lang.Float', single(10.07))

ans =   1.0927e+009
```

Answer (score 2):

### Octave's javaclasspath

First, double check that the .jar or .class file is in Octave's java path. Use this Octave command:

```
javaclasspath
```

It should output something like this:

```
   STATIC JAVA PATH

     ./path/to/your_file.jar
     ./path/to/your-other-file.class

   DYNAMIC JAVA PATH

     - empty -
```

If you don't see your .jar or .class file here, you can add it to either your static or dynamic path. There are [known issues](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?42710) with dynamic path, so I'd recommend using the static path. One way to do that is to create a javaclasspath.txt. The format of that file is one line per classpath. Example content:

```
./path/to/your-file.jar
./path/to/your-other-file.class
```

(Be sure to include ".jar" or ".class" in the filenames.)

Here's where Octave looks for that file, in order:

1. The current directory (where Octave was started)
2. User's home directory
3. In the same folder as javaclasspath.m, usually something like OCTAVE_HOME/share/octave/OCTAVE_VERSION/m/java/.

More info [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/How-to-make-Java-classes-available_003f.html).

### Debugging .jar Files

Since your Server_Client class is part of the server_console package, I'm guessing you might be using a .jar file. Let's make sure it's packaged correctly. Run

```
jar tvf path/to/your-file.jar
```

Since you're trying to access the class server_console.Server_Client, you'll want to see something like this in the output:

```
   0 Wed Sep 30 08:11:58 EDT 2015 server_console/
1893 Wed Sep 30 08:11:58 EDT 2015 server_console/Server_Client.class
```

You can also test your .jar file with this command:

```
java -cp ./path/to/your-file.jar server_console.Server_Client
```

If your .jar file is not packaged correctly, you'll see this output:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class server_console.Server_Client
```

If your .jar file is packaged correctly and you have a main method, the main method will be run.

If your .jar file is packaged correctly and you don't have a main method, you'll see this output:

```
Error: Main method not found in class server_console.Server_Client, please define the main method as:
    public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```