# create custom java object from octave - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: matlab, octave

I have written a simple custom java class

```
public class Optim {

public int optfunc(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6)
{
    return (x1^2 + x2^2 +2*x3^2 + 2*x1*x2+x1*x3-200*x1- 140*x2 + 120*x3+200);
}

}
```

Now I want to create an object of type Optim in Octave. I have created a file called javaclasspath.txt which contains only one line

```
C:\Users\Sorin\Optim.class
```

and put this file in C:\Users\Sorin along with the file Optim.class
When I start Octave I can see the following

```
>javaclasspath
STATIC JAVA PATH

  C:\Users\Sorin\Optim.class
  C:\Users\Sorin\Optim.class
 DYNAMIC JAVA PATH

  - empty -
>pwd
ans = C:\Users\Sorin
>x = javaObject('Optim')
error: [java] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Optim
```

Do you have any idea why the class is not found?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your Main method?

Comment: is it mandatory to have a main method? I thought any java class would work

Comment: Well yes it will trhow you: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
but try to do java Optim

Comment: Octave was asked just to create an instance of type Optim and not to run the class. The constructor should be enough for this.

Comment: You're right check this documentation for the correct steps [check this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/How-to-make-Java-classes-available_003f.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class path needs to contain the directory where your .class file lives. Not the .class file itself.

Comment: yes, that is! thank you. I was wrongly guided by this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32363613/trying-to-call-a-java-object-in-octave, first answer.

Comment: This contradicts the documentation? https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Making-Java-Classes-Available.html#Making-Java-Classes-Available

Comment: @stephematician I don't think so. Please point out the specific contradiction that you have found.

Comment: From the documentation: The static classpath is populated once from the contents of a plain text file named javaclasspath.txt (or classpath.txt historically) when the Java Virtual Machine starts. This file contains one line for each individual classpath to be added to the static classpath. These lines can identify single class files, _directories containing class files_, or Java archives with complete class file hierarchies.

Comment: Thanks. You are correct. In my view, this is a documentation error: "These lines can identify *single* *class* *files*".