# Importing Java Classes in Octave

Tags: java, matlab, octave

I've been having difficulty figuring out how to do this.  From [the Octave website](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.0/How-to-make-Java-classes-available_003f.html), it seems that java classes are found via a class path.  [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32877819/9377925) indicates that the "static java path" is to the "dynamic java path".  Yet I'm not sure how to set up the static java path.

In my particular situation of interest, I'm trying to use the javaplex package with Octave - I've contacted the authors of javaplex on Github and they said if Octave can load java classes, then I can use it.  Octave can do this, as far as I know.  My difficulty is the following.

I am using code written for Matlab, and the differences in how Octave and Matlab interact with Java is throwing me some trouble.  I have to set the directory for Octave to be

```
C:\...\javaplex-master\javaplex-master\dist\matlab-examples-4.3.4\matlab_examples
```

From here, I run the command "`load_javaplex`" in the command window, which runs the script "`load_javaplex.m`".  Within this script however are the lines

```
javaaddpath('./lib/javaplex.jar');

import edu.stanford.math.plex4.*;
```

where "`edu.stanford.math.plex4.*`" is a java class (the [tutorial](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~adams/research/javaplex_tutorial.pdf) also suggests running the second line explicitly).

I've figured out this doesn't work in Octave (as for Java interfacing, I can't just use Matlab code), and so I need to add it to my java classpath to access it.  Yet I don't know how to do this in Octave.  Should I save some sort of .txt file in the directory that identifies the static class path? Any general info on how I can load java classes in Octave? I am having difficulty with the information available online figuring out how to do this.  What do I do after I add something to the classpath?

Comment: I'll see if I can get it to work by following the guidelines in the manual here: https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Java-Interface.html#Java-Interface (I assume you've seen this already and couldn't figure how to get it to work). In the meantime, however, please check if `octave_config_info ("features").JAVA` outputs `1` in your system, as per this note in the wiki: https://wiki.octave.org/Java_package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is, it is very easy to translate the java instructions from matlab syntax to octave syntax.

The bad news is, you will have to translate the matlab syntax to octave syntax. While this is straightforward, it does mean you may have to hunt any java calls in the provided m-files *as well* (rather than just in your own code) and adapt the syntax. (Obviously you might come up with a nice way to automate the process instead.)

Here is how I got the [tutorial](https://github.com/appliedtopology/javaplex/wiki/Tutorial#installation-for-matlab) to work on octave:

- I downloaded the `matlab_examples` zipfile and unzipped as instructed (I unzipped the folder on my desktop, i.e. on my machine this resulted in the folder `/home/tasos/Desktop/matlab_examples`
- I open octave and `cd` into that directory
- Open the `load_javaplex.m` file and remove all `import` statements, and then run it to "initialize" javaplex.
- You are now ready to run the command `api.Plex4.createExplicitSimplexStream()` as indicated in the tutorial, BUT, first you need to note two things:

  1. Octave does not provide a way to import java classes from packages, therefore all your class calls need to be *fully* qualified by package. I.e. the `Plex4` class of the `api` package will actually need to be fully qualified as `edu.stanford.math.plex4.api.Plex4`. You can confirm `Plex4` is a class of the `api` package, which is itself a (sub)package of the `edu.stanford.math.plex4` package by opening the .jar file and exploring its folder structure.
  2. The syntax for creating java objects, calling java methods, etc, is different in octave than in matlab. See the [relevant page in the octave manual for details](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Java-Interface-Functions.html).

Therefore the `api.Plex4.createExplicitSimplexStream()`, which is intended to call  (with no arguments) the `createExplicitSimplexStream` method of the `Plex4` class in the `edu.stanford.math.plex4.api` package, will be called in octave as follows:

```
javaMethod( 'createExplicitSimplexStream', 'edu.stanford.math.plex4.api.Plex4')
```

which then outputs as the answer desribed in the tutorial.

Having said all that, note that, while you cannot `import` classes or (sub)packages directly to save you from having to rewrite long package strings all the time, octave's java interface *does* seem to rely on strings a lot, which means it is fairly easy to store such long strings as variables and reuse them at the point of having to access a class. So, e.g. you could save the string `'edu.stanford.math.plex4.'` to a variable called `plex4` and simply call `javaMethod('createExplicitSimplexStream', [plex4, 'api.Plex4'])` in your code instead, etc, which makes it *slightly* less cumbersome.

Have fun.

Comment: PS. While this should enable you to use javaplex for your own purposes, I would note that in the case of running some of the matlab examples provided explicitly, then these may fail on octave for reasons entirely unrelated to java and javaplex (i.e. the usual slight incompatibilities between matlab and octave scripts which require some slight change of syntax to get one working on the other etc).

Comment: Also, if you intend your javaplex enabled scripts to run on both matlab and octave at any point in time, then I would invest early enough in creating wrapper functions that detect which environment you're on and call the appropriate syntax respectively, and stick to using only those wrapper functions in your main scripts.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was an excellent and helpful answer.  Although annoying, I doubt the matlab/octave compatibility issues will be nearly as difficult as this, but I shouldn't speak too soon :) Thank you again, and for your help on my previous question, this has me back on track for progress!

Comment: What if I am trying to use something I should pass parameters to?  For example, if I have a matlab line "api.Plex4.createVietorisRipsStream(T2, max_dimension,max_filtration_value,num_divisions);" my octave version seems it should be "javaMethod('createVietorisRipsStream(T2, max_dimension,max_filtration_value,num_divisions),[plex, 'api.Plex4'])"; however this is not working (which seems wrong anyways).  Yet if I pass just "javaMethod('createVietorisRipsStream,[plex, 'api.Plex4'])" it still doesn't work; it gives "error: [java] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: createVietorisRipsStream"

Comment: I'm copying and pasting from a script that worked in Matlab, so it is not spelling, which I hoped :(

Comment: looking at the api.Plex4 script, it seems that createVietorisRipsStream requires one to supply an array kind of object as the first paramater ('what I have as T2'), but I'm still not sure the proper method of passing parameters in this case

Comment: I think I found a way to pass arguments here: https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.2/Java-Interface-Functions.html#XREFjavaMethod; my problem still is not being able to call "javaMethod('createVietorisRipsStream,[plex, 'api.Plex4'])" - it is in the script api.Plex4 though.  However, while for "createExplicitSimplexStream" there is this: public static ExplicitSimplexStream createExplicitSimplexStream() {...} for createVietorisRipsStream there is this: public static VietorisRipsStream<double[]> createVietorisRipsStream(...){...}; could it be related to the "<double[]>" in the Vietoris Rips line?

Comment: feel free to create a new question if you have a more specific problem, preferably with a testcase / minimal working example, and I'd be happy to look for it. But, more generally, have a look at the documentation first; the page on Java Interfaces states clearly that the syntax for javamethod is   `javamethod( "<name of method as string>", "<name of class as string, fully qualified with packages>", argument1, argument2, argument3, ...etc)`. Therefore the correct call should be `javamethod( 'createVietorisRpisStream', [plex, 'api.Plex4'], T2, max_dimension,max_filtration_value,num_divisions)`

Comment: also, the arguments may or may not have to be converted into java objects themselves first. (but presumably if it's simple 'double' objects then octave handles this conversion implicitly)

Comment: and as for 'arrays' in java through octave, again read the Java Chapter in the manual carefully (it is very short!). In [this page](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/How-to-use-Java-from-within-Octave.html#How-to-use-Java-from-within-Octave) it states clearly that: _"Via `javaObject` one may create all kinds of Java objects except arrays. The latter are created through `javaArray`. "_

Comment: I've posted this as a question with more clear details