# Difficulty with Octave's "javaMethod"

Tags: java, matlab, octave

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51802175/9377925) question, I was trying to import java classes into `Octave`.  In my particular example, I was (and am) working with `javaplex`, a set of java tools with code for implementation in `Matlab`.  The answer to the question shows that, whereas in `Matlab` you would do the following:

```
import edu.stanford.math.plex4.*;

api.Plex4.createExplicitSimplexStream();
```

The answer provided in the question showed that the way to do this in `Octave` is

```
javaMethod( 'createExplicitSimplexStream', 'edu.stanford.math.plex4.api.Plex4')
```

This was working excellently, but then I ran into a strange problem.  There is another method called `createVietorisRipsStream`.  In `Matlab`, I would run this with a line such as the following:

```
api.Plex4.createVietorisRipsStream(parameters);
```

So I would think that the equivalent command in `Octave` would be

```
javaMethod( 'createVietorisRipsStream', 'edu.stanford.math.plex4.api.Plex4')
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
error: [java] java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: createVietorisRipsStream
```

I'm not sure why this error is coming up, and both are in the same JAVA file ('Plex4').  I did take a look at the Plex4 file, and there are two differences between `createExplicitSimplexStream` and `createVietorisRipsStream` that I noticed:

1. There are two instances of `createExplicitSimplexStream` and six instances of `createVietorisRipsStream`
2. There is bit that says `<double[]>`.  I don't know if that is relevant however (I haven't read or wrote much java, up to this point, I've been able to use the [tutorial they provided](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~adams/research/javaplex_tutorial.pdf) to only use Matlab and not have to look under the hood).

Here is one example of the code from the Plex4 file for a `createExplicitSimplexStream`:

```
public static ExplicitSimplexStream createExplicitSimplexStream(double maxFiltrationValue) {
    return new ExplicitSimplexStream(maxFiltrationValue);
}
```

Here is one example of the code from the Plex4 file for a `createVietorisRipsStream`:

```
public static VietorisRipsStream<double[]> createVietorisRipsStream(double[][] points, int maxDimension, double maxFiltrationValue, int numDivisions) {
    return FilteredStreamInterface.createPlex4VietorisRipsStream(points, maxDimension, maxFiltrationValue, numDivisions);
}
```

Any idea of why I'm getting the error I'm getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the octave documentation for the Java section properly, it's only 4 pages, and it explains this well!

As I mentioned in the comments in the previous question, the way to call a java method *with arguments* is:

> `javamethod`(
>       `name of method as a string`,
>       `name of class fully qualified with packages as a string`,
>       `method's first argument`,
>       `method's second argument`,
>       `... etc`
>      )

This is the only way to call 'static' methods; with normal 'instance' methods, you can either use `javaMethod` and replace the name of the class by the java object itself, or simply use it as you would in java, i.e. `objectname.methodname(arg1, arg2, ... etc)`

I have implemented here the tutorial for you to have a look at (page 14 in the pdf). (don't forget to run the modified 'load_javaplex' script first).

```
octave:2> max_dimension = 3;
octave:3> max_filtration_value = 4;
octave:4> num_divisions = 1000;
octave:5> point_cloud = javaMethod( 'getHouseExample', 'edu.stanford.math.plex4.examples.PointCloudExamples')
point_cloud =

<Java object: double[][]>

octave:6> stream = javaMethod( 'createVietorisRipsStream', 'edu.stanford.math.plex4.api.Plex4', point_cloud, max_dimension, max_filtration_value, num_divisions) 
stream =

<Java object: edu.stanford.math.plex4.streams.impl.VietorisRipsStream>

octave:7> persistence = javaMethod( 'getModularSimplicialAlgorithm', 'edu.stanford.math.plex4.api.Plex4', max_dimension, 2)
persistence =

<Java object: edu.stanford.math.plex4.autogen.homology.IntAbsoluteHomology>

octave:8> intervals = persistence.computeIntervals(stream)
intervals =

<Java object: edu.stanford.math.plex4.homology.barcodes.BarcodeCollection>
```

(I have not gone further because plot_barcodes needs to be modified a bit too; it's only a couple of lines but it would be too much to post here, the reasoning is the same though).

Also, if you're not sure what is meant by class constructors, class methods, and static vs instance-specific methods, unfortunately this is more to do with java, although it should be pretty introductory stuff. It is well worth reading up a bit about it first.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much!  I got it running :) After messing around with it, I see my problem was two-fold: 1.) I thought that I wouldn't need to enter any parameters, and it would have some default settings and 2.) that I could enter in a matlab style array, and the method would somehow handle the conversion.  I guess these were pretty naive to assume.  Some of these questions may have seemed obvious in retrospect, but this has truly been a learning experience so far in understanding java a bit better.  I'll read up on it more, and thank you again!  I'll be sure to read documentation more carefully

Comment: @Chris You're welcome, glad to hear it. I *would* write a note to the javaplex developers if I were you, pointing out that there is demand for out-of-the-box octave compatibility, and that it is extremely trivial for them to provide this on their part (but not so much for the user, since they would have to translate all of the provided functions manually -- which is straightforward but tedious and unnecessary). I would also point out octave's rising popularity (partly thanks to Andrew Ng's excellent Machine Learning nanodegree course on Coursera). Redirect them to these two questions even.

Comment: @Chris equally, if _you_ want to ensure matlab compatibility with your octave scripts (and vice-versa), just wrap any javaplex related calls to an `if isOctave` block, as defined here: https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/How-to-Distinguish-Between-Octave-and-Matlab.html

Comment: I'll send them an email letting them know.  Thanks for the matlab compatibility info!  Again, this has been a huge help