# Trouble Understanding/Locating a Jar file (JIDT package) needed for Octave to Java Array Conversion

Tags: java, octave

In [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51852094/9377925), I was trying to rework some Matlab code and figure out a package called javaplex to be compatible with Octave; it uses Java, but is tooled for Matlab, hence *that* issue.  Now in an interval of time, I was busy/running simulations, and hadn't gotten around to a final step - actually using the package, with most all of the difficulties worked out.  It turns out that another step exists: I need to convert an Octave array to a Java array (although I'm not sure why this issue didn't come up in Matlab).

To do so, I have turned to [this script](https://github.com/jlizier/jidt/blob/master/demos/octave/octaveToJavaDoubleMatrix.m), in which the comments indicate that when using it, it

> Assumes the JIDT [Java Information Dynamics Toolkit] jar is already on the java classpath - you will get a java classpath error if this is not the case.

So I go to the [JIDT GitHub page](https://github.com/jlizier/jidt) and download this package.  Now I am not a very avid user of java, so I believe I am failing to see something fairly straightforward: I am not sure where the "JIDT jar" is that is referenced in the above block quote!  I can't find such a particular jar file to put in Octave's java classpath.  In [this tutorial for JIDT](https://github.com/jlizier/jidt/blob/master/course/Module3-JIDT/Lec3-IntroToJIDT.pdf), they say you need the "infodynamics.jar" file in the classpath (page 9).  I'm not sure what jar file I should be looking for, and where.  Any help understanding the nature, name and location of this jar file (within the infodynamics toolkit folder) would be appreciated!

As an inevitable follow-up question, because this will come up upon resolving this issue, I would like to clarify the following procedure is how to add a jar file to the Octave (static) java classpath (following [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32877819/9377925), I wasn't sure if I was implementing correctly):

1. I create a file called "javaclasspath.txt" inside of the directory I use in Octave.
2. I enter the name of files as follows: "./path/to/your-file.jar"

I suppose my main issue here is where do I start the path (all the way back with "C:/..."?), and do I put this "javaclasspath.txt" file in the directory folder I will be using most of the time in Octave?

Edit: I cannot find "infodynamics.jar" as shown here:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried octave's [JavaArray](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Java-Interface-Functions.html#XREFjavaArray) method for this?  The issue doesn't come up in matlab because matlab's internal representation of arrays is compatible with java's and the conversion is handled implicitly.   (the matlab interpreter itself is written in java afaik; octave is written in c++)

Comment: As for the classpath, I think relying on the dynamic method is fine, (i.e. use the function `javaaddpath('c:\path\to\infodynamics.jar');` etc). If you remember from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802175/importing-java-classes-in-octave) this is how javaplex does it too. But yes, a static class path as per the [octave manual](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Making-Java-Classes-Available.html#Making-Java-Classes-Available) is fine too. Do whichever is simplest for you.

Comment: I'll try that out.  I've had issues with JavaArray before, because it seems to make a JavaArray, but I do not know how to use it to convert an Octave array into a JavaArray.  It asks as (correct me if I am wrong) the class/type of objects to be inside of the array, and then arguments for the size of the array.  How then to fill in the result javaArray with the Octave Array?  To be honest, I did not work hard on this problem, because I took the existence of the infodynamics package to mean that it was in fact hard to convert Octave to Java arrays.  If this is not so though, that would be great!

Comment: you would fill it same way as you would in java, i.e., presumably via a for loop, or using some special function provided by java or your library (e.g. javaplex).

Comment: I feel bad saying this, but this route isn't very easy for me (compared to using infodynamics I guess), as I'm not too familiar with java.  Looking at the code for the example java arrays in javaplex, it doesn't appear itself that hard, but I feel like I'd encounter a battery of annoying issues.  I suppose Octave support in javaplex would necessarily include that though... but then again there is infodynamics

Comment: of course! You should use whatever method saves you time and trouble! It's not like you're "cheating on octave", hahah. I only suggested trying the octave native method because I suspect the reverse scenario to what you describe is more likely to happen: i.e. that infodynamics might appear simple now but come with an overhead of trouble later on, since it is built for a particular purpose which is different to yours. But, equally, it might not! Just try what you think is best. Having said that, if you'd like to ask a separate question on how to use javaArray I'm happy to answer it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JIDT jar is named infodynamics.jar and it is located in the root of the downloads infodynamics-dist-1.4.zip file.

Comment: I've put a picture in my answer to show that I am unable to find this "infodynamics.jar" file in the folder

Comment: Right, it looks like we went through different paths: I went via the github wiki-> downloads -> Full distributions, ie. http://lizier.me/joseph/software/jidt/download.php?file=infodynamics-dist-1.4.zip